# Sorting an Array with Doubles Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I'm reading a text file into a 2D array. The first column ( the one I'm sorting on) is almost all Doubles. As you all probably know, it sorts 1.1  1.6  25.6  6.4, how can I fix this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/evanlivingston/2d.txt");
        PrintStream pout = new PrintStream(out);
        List<String[]> entries = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/Users/evanlivingston/dists/0.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            entries.add(new String[] { sc.next(), sc.next()});
        }
        String[][] table = entries.toArray(new String[0][]);

        Arrays.sort(table, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
                String t1 = s1[0];
                String t2 = s2[0];
                return t1.compareTo(t2);               
            }      
        });
        pout.print(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(table));
        pout.close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Here is my updated code. It won't compile.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/evanlivingston/2d.txt");
        PrintStream pout = new PrintStream(out);
        List<Coords> coords = new ArrayList<Coords>();
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/Users/evanlivingston/dists/0.txt"));
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] numstrs = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
            }
            String[][] table = coords.toArray(new String[0][]);

            Arrays.sort(table, new Comparator<Double[]>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Double[] s1, Double[] s2) {
                    double a = Double.parseDouble(s1);
                    double b = Double.parseDouble(s2);
                    compare(a, b);
                }
            });
            pout.print(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(table));
            pout.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **almost** all Doubles? And by "Double" here, I assume you really mean "text that can be interpreted as a floating-point number per the usual conventions, which I wish to sort according to the resulting floating-point value rather than lexicographically".

Comment: @Karl Knecthel, yes, that's exactly what I mean, I edited to code to be what I assume to be correct, but it wont compile.

Comment: it's good that you're editing to follow up, but please add to the original post instead of overwriting. Overwriting removes the context for the original answers, making them look inappropriate for the question.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus, I'm not sure I can add code without editing my original post as Im limited to 555 characters or so in the comments, is there a way around this?

Comment: You're right to want to edit instead of using comments. But you should add the new code separately. It's the difference between "append" and "replace." I edited to your post to illustrate. This works better when you don't change quite so much between versions of the code.

Answer (score 6):

Store doubles in the array NOT Strings.

So convert the String to a double when you read it in from your file. Or use the Scanner.nextDouble() method to do this for you.

You don't want to be converting the Strings every time the Comparator is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing `String` values, not `Double` values, so 2 comes after 1 and before 6.

To fix this, you should convert your values to actual `Double` objects with the wrapper method `valueOf()` ([documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)).

**EDIT**:
I went for the simpler fix above, but camickr's answer is better if you care at all about performance.

Regarding your update not compiling, multiple things are wrong. Did you ever declare a second `compare()` method anywhere? There's nothing built in for that. Recursively calling the existing `compare()` won't help in your case.

On that note, you can't call the existing `compare()`; autoboxing won't convert primitive `double`s into arrays of `Double` objects. And there's no way to parse `Double` arrays into primitive `double`s.

Since you're trying to use primitive `double`s now, you could just use the plain old `>` and `<` operators to compare with instead of the more complex `Comparator` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing strings, not numeric values. 1 is lexically lower than 2, and 2 is lexically lower than three. So from a string perspective, 234 is less than 3. You have to convert your `doubles` from `strings` in order to compare them properly. In Java you do this via:

`double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(aString);`

so your final expression should really be

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(firstString);
double b = Double.parseDouble(secondString);
compare(a,b);
```

Comment: I was about to upvote this, but the primitive `double` doesn't have the ability to use the `compareTo()` method.

Comment: Really? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo(java.lang.Double)

Comment: The link is for a "Double" object. Your code is for a "double" primitive. You can't invoke methods on a primitive.

Comment: Really. Try to compile it, see what happens.

Comment: Does it compile with `compare()` for you? I can't get it to. Unless you're importing something that you haven't mentioned, your update hasn't fixed anything.

Answer (score -1):

Have your comparator convert the strings it is input into doubles and do a numeric comparison rather than a string compare.

That's the advantage of the `Comparator` concept.  It can do anything with the inputs.  So if you need to sort `Strings` as if they were numbers, write a `Comparator` that'll do just that.